# Array to string conversion while trying to get product collection

Tags: magento2, collection

I'm trying to get a product collection. I got it by function:

```
public function getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->setPageSize(3);

    return $collection;
}
```

And my template file is:

```
$productCollection = $block->getProductCollection();
foreach($productCollection as $product) {
    echo $product->getData() . "<br />";
}
```

But I got an error `Array to string conversion` in this line:

```
echo $product->getData() . "<br />";
```

Could someone tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$product->getData()` returns an `array`. you cannot echo an array.

Try with `echo "<pre>"; print_r($product->getData())` or `echo "<pre>"; var_dump($product->getData())`

Comment: But why it displayed an arrays of products instead of a real products?

Comment: not sure I understand your question. show an example of what you were expecting.

Comment: I was expecting that when I'll get a product collection, products (that I had imported manually in the admin panel) will be displayed. Instead, it displays five seperate product arrays, which is `key => value` pairs, not a real products (that I have imported.

Answer (score 1):

you need to store the $collection=$product->getData(); and then use foreach loop to get the content . 
actually mistake you did was trying to use echo function on $product->getData().

above function was returning and array and you were trying to print it .

echo functions generally fails in this situation . **@marius** suggested you correct function to get content of an array.